# English Inference question - Disagree with given answer

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english

I have a statement based off a paragraph of text. The questions asks if this statement follows or not. The answer is supposedly that the statement follows but I am not sure that it does.

---

**Text:**

A credit is awarded for each exam where a student ranks in the top fifth of the year for that exam. Students who get two or more credits **without failing an exam** get a distinction.

**Statement:**
Students must rank in the top fifth of the year for more than one exam to earn a distinction.

---

I don't think this follows because it says that students must rank in the top fifth of the year for more than one exam but fails to mention that this must be done without failing an exam. So to me the statement sounds like it's saying that you only need to rank top fifth in more than one exam to obtain a distinction, which I think is incomplete.

Please advise me on this, as I have already asked the question writer and they have told me that because it says "**to**" and not "**will**" earn a distinction, that the question does not need to state all requirements.

Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as asked, it's a matter of logic, not English. A distinction cannot be achieved *unless* an exam is passed, but that's already given. The statement that's the result of *if this statement follows* is still a true statement. Whether or not it's a *complete* statement is not what the instructions ask. The question could be about what *if this statement* ***follows*** means, but that would need to be clarified; barring such clarification, I fail to see how any answer could not be opinion-based (which is also a reason for closing the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A credit is awarded for each exam where a student ranks in the top fifth of the year for that exam. Students who get two or more credits without failing an exam get a distinction.

Statement: Students must rank in the top fifth of the year for more than one exam  (q) to earn a distinction (p).* (p ===> q, read "p implies q)

It is equivalent to say  1/ "To earn a distinction students must rank in the top fifth of the year for more than one exam ", (*which is not too precise: "as a requirement to earn a …" would have been better, sufficiently explicit.*)
which can be said as
2/"**If** students earn a distinction **then** they must rank in the top fifth of the year for more than two exams. (*which is not saying that if they rank in the top fifth … they necessarily have a distinction*)

---

The subtlety is in the reading of the statement; you read it like this;

top fifth for > 2 exams (q) =====> distinction (p)

which is not the right way; the statement means that q is a **necessity (must)**,  **in order to have p (earn)**, which in logic is "p ===> q".That is, if the distinction is earned then you know that the students must rank in the top fifth of the year for more than one exam (q); that is all that the statement says; it merely state one of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to explain points 1, 2, and 3 and show the relationship between exams, the position in those, and credits and distinctions.

Point 1 speaks of credits

Point 2 addresses the criteria for distinctions

Point 3 states the requirement for a distinction but does not mention those who fail an exam and are thus excluded.

The whole thing is poorly written.

[image: Flowchart of Credits and Distinctions]

Comment: This is exactly the way I see it, the statement (point 3) is poorly written, but the author is telling me that because he said 'to' earn, he does not need to have written all requirements. He said that all requirements would only have had to be included if the statement had ended with 'will' earn a distinction. It is not explicit enough and so as you say it is poorly written.

Answer (score 0):

The truth of the “Statement” would logically and necessarily follow from the truth of the “Text“ if the specified conditions for getting a “credit” and for getting a “distinction” were necessary as well sufficient; but the “Text” asserts merely that they are sufficient. That is, nowhere is it said that there is no *other* way to gain either a credit or a distinction, such as by washing the examiner’s car or mucking out his chicken coop. Such possibilities would allow for getting a “distinction” without fulfilling the condition specified in the “Statement.”